# JApplet not working - page becomes unresponsive when plugin enabled

Tags: java, applet, japplet

I am trying to run an Applet in a browser. I have three libraries, `commons-net.jar`, `Jsch.jar` (referenced) and `MyApplet.jar`, in the same folder on my local machine.

I created the following HTML file `try.html`:

```
<html>
<head> 
<title> 
HelloApplet by Aditya Jain
</title>
</head>
<body>  
<Applet  Code = 'com.cisco.fastforward.main/Main_Applet.class'
     Archive = 'MyApplet.jar,commons-net-3.3.jar,jsch-0.1.51.jar'
     Width =900 height = 900>
</Applet>
</body>
</html>
```

When I load the HTML file, it initially says "plug-in blocked". After I  enable the plugin and reload, the page becomes unresponsive and I don't get any console output.

Update - The browser i was using was Chrome and Safari , When i switched to Firefox 25.0 , it worked after a few permissions.
I dont know why this happened.
Any reasons?(latest Chrome and Safari used)

Comment: commons-net and jsch may generate security exceptions as they are designed to make connections to other networks (amongst other things).  Check the console output of your applet

Comment: Like i said , it didnt even start and i had no console output

Comment: Does it run in the IDE?

Comment: Yeah it runs well in the AppletViewer in eclipse

Comment: Be sure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show.  If there is no output at the default level, raise the level and try it again.

Comment: The Java Console is configured to "Show Console" and in the debugging level , i had enabled everything but still while running in Chrome , i got nothing but a unresponsive page

Answer (score 0):

Sign your jar. Set your system path to java path in cmd. Then run jarsigner, create a keystore and sign your jar. Make sure you have a proper manifest in your jar as well for permissions purposes. Also set java security to low and add your local html file to the java security exception list. This is the only way to make an applet work right now.

Comment: I have signed the jar , I am not sure how to check the manifest in the Jar , i have added the HTML file as an exception . I cant set the Java security to low , only options available are high and very high after the recent update.

Comment: If it still doesn't work then go into java control panel enable console and print the output. The console will start automatically when you launch an applet. If this doesn't work then there is a runtime error in your code most-likely.